# Clear input field created by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am doing an ng-repeat and creating inputfields based on a dynamic nr of players.

```
<div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="p in players" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <h2>{{p.name}}</h2>

        <div ng-repeat="po in p.points">
          <p class=""><span>Round: {{po.Round}}</span> {{po.Point}}p </p>
        </div>
        <p>Total: {{p.total}}</p>
        <p ng-if="p.gameover == true">GAME OVER</p>
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="newpoint$index"></label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="newpoint$index" ng-model="p.newpoint" ng-if="p.gameover == false" placeholder="Enter points">
            <button ng-click="updatePoint(p.id, p.newpoint)" ng-if="p.gameover == false" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">+</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
</div>
```

And this is the updatePoint function:

```
$scope.updatePoint = function (playerid, point) {
  var currentRound = $scope.players[playerid].points.length + 1;
    var pointObjToPush = {Round: currentRound, Point: point};
    $scope.players[playerid].points.push(pointObjToPush);
    $scope.players[playerid].total += point;
    if ($scope.players[playerid].total >= 200) {
        $scope.players[playerid].gameover = true;
    }
};
```

Now, my question is: Each time the user adds a point to a player, I want that inputfield to be cleared, but I have no idea how to reach that spicifik inputfield using angular. I could do it with jquery but I would rather do it with angular if possible. I think I should add some form of directive on the inputfields that get created and trigger it from the updatePoint function to clear the field but I dont know how that would be done exactly.

Edit:
This is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XYmZc9aJ6RQzVJzDoMDQ) I'm working on

Comment: Does anybody have any advice on this one?

Comment: that plunkr is pretty incomplete and doesn't make it easy to play with your code. you could write a directive for this, or use ngSubmit https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit